# Как оповещать пользователя о новом сообщении?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

есть небольшой чат, где пользователи могут общаться друг с другом, держится это все на django, channels и websocket
Нужно, чтобы при отправке сообщения одним юзером другому приходило уведомление
Я в небольшом замешательстве, так как везде пишут про открытие отдельного потока, слушающего все чаты, а их может быть много, и посылающего в случае обновления чата уведомление
Как по мне, способ крайне варварский
Но идея что-то отправлять дополнительное от пользователя, написавшего сообщения, ещё хуже, так как в таком случае получатся постоянные ненужные серверу запросы
Подскажите пожалуйста, какую архитектуру лучше применить для такой задачи?

Comment: "Как по мне, способ крайне варварский " --- в чём заключается варварство?

Comment: Потому что чатов может быть 1000, и для для каждого открывать поток и добавлять в группу мне видется решением довольно сомнительным
Пока я искал ответ, у меня созрела мысль:
А что, если отслеживать через websocket изменения в сообщениях пользователя, и в случае обнаружения таковых уже выполнять всю нужную работу?
Вопрос лишь в том, как "повесить событие" на изменение данных юзера в бд